# How to pass a token from a backend to a frontend application

Tags: php, authentication, single-sign-on

My problem is the following:
[image]

I have a javascript Application which can be hosted anywhere (in a different domain than my backend). 
My app already exist and communicate with my backend (php/symfony2) with a custom token. I need to implement SSO, so a SSO button on the app will redirect to SSO.external.com which can be google or a custom sso provider. The SAML token will be sent to my backend where I can verify the user and generate my app token.

The problem is: how do I send it back to my javascript app ? I am not allowed to put it in the url and redirect from my backend to my app.
I have two ideas for now:

- Implement [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) in order to communicate between a window on my backend and a window on my javascript app (never used it, just land into this documentation)
- Or set a cookie in my backend domain, make an ajax call from the javascript app to my backend domain and depending on the cookie it will return the token

My two solutions seems like workarounds, do someone have a better way to do it ?